# Outputting geojson collection with element-api

Tags: plugins, plugin-elementapi

I am trying to get the element-api to output  a valid geojson collection.

The way the keys are set in the returned data make me think it isnt possible.

To produce a valid string of json i am having currently to do this to prefix the geojson collection in the correct format:

```
const geoData = JSON.stringify({"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [data.features[0]]})
```

I'd rather do this in the endpoint but unfortunately I need to set the "type": "FeatureCollection" at the resourcekey or above - this doesn't seem possible as it seems limited to just passing a string and not an array to resourcekey. For example to get the collection output format right Id need a resource key like this:

```
'resourceKey' => ['type' => 'FeatureCollection', ['features']],
```

but this produces an error.
My return endpoint looks like below:

```
return [
                'resourceKey' => 'features',
                'elementType' => Entry::class,
                'criteria' => $criteria,
                'paginate' => false,
                'pretty' => true,
                'cache' => false,
                'transformer' => function (craft\elements\Entry $entry) {
                    return [
                        'type' => 'Feature',
                        'properties' => [
                            'id' => $entry->id,
                            'title' => $entry->title,
                            'localauthority' => $entry->ladnm,
                            'mapitAreaId' => $entry->mapitAreaId,
                            'fundableRegion' => $entry->fundableRegion,
                            'openForFunding' => $entry->openForFunding,
                            'lsoacode' => $entry->lsoacode
                        ],
                        'geometry' => json_decode($entry->geojson)
                    ];
                },
            ];
```

Is there a way around this? Im on Craft 3.x and graphQl wasnt an option as json support wasn't historically good for my data:)

Comment: What's the error??

Comment: resourceKey only accepts a string not an array I think..